# How to come to the ending point of a maze?

Tags: python, numpy, maze

In my code in the **read_file method** I am reading a file and returning an 2d array that contains the lines of the maze.
E.g. [[1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0], [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]]

2 is the starting point in the maze and 3 is the ending point of the maze.

```
import numpy as np

class Maze:
    @staticmethod
    def read_file(file):
        """ function that reads the file and returns the content of the file in an array """
        # dict for replacements
        replacements = {'*': 0, ' ': 1, 'A': 2, 'B': 3}
        # open and read file
        file = open(file, "r")
        lines = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        # row and col count
        rows = len(lines)
        cols = len(lines[0]) - 1
        # create array
        maze_array = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=int)
        # add lines to array
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            for i in range(0, len(line) - 1):
            # replace line content with the ones from the dictionary and add it to the array
            maze_array[index][i] = replacements.get(line[i], line[i])
        return maze_array
```

Now I want to go through the maze and get the ending point, starting at the starting point. For that I have written a method called **search**. In this method I check the cells of the maze.
When a cell equals 3 I have found the end of the maze. Equals 0 is a wall and equals 1 is an empty cell where I can go through. After going through the cells I set them to 4 to mark it as visited. Then the recursive calls below.

```
     @staticmethod
    def search(x, y, array):
        """
           0: wall
           1: empty
           2: starting point
           3: ending point
           4: visited cell
        """
        if array[x][y] == 3:
            print('end at %d,%d' % (x, y))
            return True
        elif array[x][y] == 0:
            print('wall at %d,%d' % (x, y))
            return False
        elif array[x][y] == 4:
            print('visited at %d,%d' % (x, y))
            return False

        print('visiting %d,%d' % (x, y))

        array[x][y] == 4

        if ((x < len(array) - 1 and Maze.search(x + 1, y, array))
            or (y > 0 and Maze.search(x, y - 1, array))
            or (x > 0 and Maze.search(x - 1, y, array))
            or (y < len(array) - 1 and Maze.search(x, y + 1, array))):
        return True

    return False


def main():
    """ Launcher """
    # [1][1] is starting point
    array = Maze.read_file("maze-one.txt")
    Maze.search(1, 1, array)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It doesn't work. I have changed my code thanks to @Florian H, but I still get following error:

```
 RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

But I need to go through the whole maze to get the ending point. Is this possible with recursive calls or is it too much? Is there any other solution than using recursive calls?

Comment: instead of calling recursively at every cell, only call recursively at intersections. This will improve the stack requirement but it may be not enough. I'd suggest using an array or list instead of the stack to store intersection points that you want to go back to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reload your file in your recursive function with

```
array = Maze.read_file('maze-one.txt')
```

in every recursion step, thus `array[x][y] == 4` will be overwritten by the reload every time.
That means your maze is always unvisited and your recursion is infinite.

**edit to your comment**

I'm not saying that you should use a global variable, but that would be an option.
In your case i would prefer a function parameter.

First of all, you neither need a `self` parameter in a static method nor an object of a class with static elements only, but thats a different topic and to much to explain here. You might read about OOP yourself.

You can give the maze as a function parameter like follows:

```
def search(x, y, array):
    ...
```

than you call it from your main method like:

```
def main():
    """ Launcher """
    # [1][1] is starting point
    Maze.search(1, 1, Maze.load_file('maze-one.txt'))
```

remove the load_file line from your `search` function and change the `Maze.search` function calls in your search method the same way.

```
 if ((x < len(array) - 1 and Maze.search(x + 1, y, array))...
```

**Second edit**

I'm not really getting the if part of your search function. But instinctively i would split that into single if's similar to the following:

```
if x < len(array) -1:
    if Maze.search(x + 1, y, array):
        return True

if y > 0:
    if Maze.search(x, y - 1, array):
        return True

if x > 0:
    if Maze.search(x - 1, y, array):
        return True

if y < len(array):
    Maze.search(x, y + 1, array):
        return True

return False
```

Comment: Do you want to say that I should change that to a global variable? Do you know how to?

Comment: @ Florian H: The thing about the self parameter is clear, these methods weren't static before and I forgot to change them. I corrected the code like you said above but I still get the same error about the recursive depth exceed. Do you know why?

Comment: `array[x][y] == 4` needs to be `array[x][y] = 4` . Btw you should leave the original code because to other people the answer won't make sense if you edit the changes into the question.

Comment: @ Florian H: thanks. By editing this one the code finally doesn't end in a RecursionError. But the algorithm does not find the end even though there is one and the way is passable.